# How to install the demo templates in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

I just buy a template from the themeforest "vision-multipurpose-joomla-template". I see the demo before buy that template. Now I want to install the same template on my website

Can anybody tell me how can I apply the same demo as the themeforest's demo shows me?

I am new in joomla and also in themeforest.Any expert please help me

Thanks

Comment: You'll only be able do easily do this if they provide a quickstart package, which contains Joomla **and** the template all in one zip file. Else you will simply have to install the template and add all the demo data manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

themeforest can be an odd place to buy a plugin. It is a marketplace. You must double-check if the template factory is well-known and don't have bad reviews.

Top template factories frequently include these resources with a theme:

- **The template**, xxx-9.9.9-template.zip (version numbers are important)
- **A quick-start or launcher**, xxx-9.9.9-launcher.zip, this installer is an installable Joomla CMS, but it has been customized to match the demo site. It rarely includes the same demo images, but it has the same layout with boxes.
- **Resources**, related assets to create background, logos, etc.
- **The framework**, most well-known templates implement a framework to generate pages and configure settings. For example: Gantry, T3, Yoo, etc.
- **Support Service**. A site where you can ask pre-sales and support questions (so you don't have to ask here ;-) )

If the template provider does not provide these elements, (in my opinion) it is not a good template that will not be flexible. For example, it will have fixed colors or a static grid layout.

Ref: [JWC15 - Why doesn’t my site look like the demo?!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPVP-gNze7o)